# Geshi filter not highlighting

Tags: 7

Using Drupal 7.22, Geshi filter 7.x-1.2 and libraries 7.x-2.1

Checked a checkbox "use Geshi filter" in a FULL HTML filter, but still when i'm trying to use something like that:

```
<php>
echo 'some code'; // not highlighting at all :X
</php>
```

Not highlighting at all, it just print echo 'some code'; not just some code, because its not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you download the geshi library into your sites/all/libraries folder

Comment: Yes in /sites/all/libraries/geshi

Comment: When you typed the code in the body field, did you set the filter to full html

Comment: Yes it's set to FULL HTML